# Returning a ResponseEntity Object with different type of body using the lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

Is it possible to return a ResponseEntity Object with different type of a body using the lambdas expression?
In the code below i have got of course a bad return type.

```
competenceRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(postCompetenceDTO.getName()).map(competence -> {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Competence already exist!", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }).orElseGet(() -> {
            Competence competence = new Competence();
            competence.setName(postCompetenceDTO.getName());

            return new ResponseEntity<CompetenceDTO>(competence.convertToCompetenceDTO(),HttpStatus.OK);
        });
```

Regards,
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you need to specify `Object` in your `ResponseEntity`, so you can put anything in it. Also you can get rude from excessive braces.

```
competenceRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(postCompetenceDTO.getName())
        .map(c -> new ResponseEntity<Object>("Competence already exist!", HttpStatus.CONFLICT))
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            Competence competence = new Competence();
            competence.setName(postCompetenceDTO.getName());
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(competence.convertToCompetenceDTO(), HttpStatus.OK);
});
```

Hope it helps!